# To find some words in a text file using regex and later print them in a different text file

Tags: regex, string, printing, line, findall

I need to find some words such as inherited, INHERITANCE, Ingeritable, etc., using regex, in a text file (origin.txt) and later I want to print them in a new text file (origin_spp.txt) and the line where they were found.

This is my code

```
re_pattern_string = r'(?:inherit|INHERIT|Inherit)*\w'

print('Opening origin.txt')
with open('origin.txt', 'r') as in_stream:
    print('Opening origin_spp.txt')
    with open('origin_spp.txt', 'w') as out_stream:
        for num, line in enumerate (in_stream):
        re_pattern_object = re.compile(re_pattern_string)
        line = line.strip()
        inherit_list = line.split()
        temp_list = re_pattern_object.findall('line')
        complete = origin_list.append('temp_list')
        for word in temp_list:
            out_stream.write(str(num) + '\t{0}\n'.format(word))

print("Done!")
print('origin.txt is closed?', in_stream.closed)
print('origin_spp.txt is closed?', out_stream.closed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(temp_list)
```

Can you help me, please? I am not getting anything and I do not know where is the error.

Thank you in advance

I need to print the words that I want to find in the origin.txt in a different text file.

This new file must contain the number of the line in the origin.txt plus the word/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had some problems:

- It's redundant to define re.compile inside for.
- for re_pattern_object.findall('line') and origin_list.append('temp_list') don't wrap variables with `''`
- with `findall` we don't need iterate lines, it's works for whole text.

Because you didn't provide input and output I just guess what you want:

```python
import re

re_pattern_string = r'((?:inherit|INHERIT|Inherit)(\w*))'
originmain_list = []
re_pattern_object = re.compile(re_pattern_string)
print('Opening origin.txt')
with open('origin.txt', 'r') as in_stream:
    print('Opening origin_spp.txt')
    with open('origin_spp.txt', 'w') as out_stream:
        for num, line in enumerate(in_stream):
            temp_list = re_pattern_object.findall(line)
            for word in temp_list:
                out_stream.write(str(num) + '\t{0}\n'.format(word[0]))
                originmain_list.append((num, word[0]))

print("Done!")
print('origin.txt is closed?', in_stream.closed)
print('origin_spp.txt is closed?', out_stream.closed)
print(originmain_list)
```

if `origin.txt` contains:

```
inheritxxxxxxx some text INHERITccccc some text
Inheritzzzzzzzz some text
inherit some text INHERIT some text
Inherit some text
```

the output in the `origin_spp.txt` will be

```
0   inheritxxxxxxx
0   INHERITccccc
1   Inheritzzzzzzzz
2   inherit
2   INHERIT
3   Inherit
```

The command line output will be:

```
Opening origin.txt
Opening origin_spp.txt
Done!
origin.txt is closed? True
origin_spp.txt is closed? True
[(0, 'inheritxxxxxxx'), (0, 'INHERITccccc'), (1, 'Inheritzzzzzzzz'), (2, 'inherit'), (2, 'INHERIT'), (3, 'Inherit')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry about the output but what I need is something like 352 Inheritance
662 inherited
785  inheritance
880 INHERITANCE. However, what I got with your suggestion was: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "origin_spp_2.py", line 35, in <module>
    re_pattern_object = re.compile(re_pattern_string)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 668, in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 29
I do not why. I really appreciate your help

Comment: You want to count the number occurrence of this words ?

Comment: please provide your desired input and output in question

Comment: No, I want that the new text file (origin_spp.txt) shows the number of the line where the words that I am looking for appear in the origin.txt. IMPUT: (number of line + required word). OUTPUT: 352 Inheritance 662 inherited 785 inheritance 880 INHERITANCE

Comment: @efp0018 I updated the solution, check it

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new using this. How can I do that? Just adding a comment? or how?